# Why do files with 'No Changes' show up in a Pull Request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

[image]
Why files with 'no changes' show up in the Pull Request? There are quite a bit of these that I'd like to clean out.. is there a way to remove them from the PR?

Comment: A local diff using a proper tool might help narrow it down. Wild guess: their execute bit was changed? Or maybe you're ignoring whitespace changes and the files only have whitespace changes? Based on a screenshot we can't do much more than guess.

Answer (score 4):

It may be whitespace changes, which are not showed by your online tool by default.

Comment: Actually, whitespace changes _are_ shown in GitHub's diff view by default. But they can be disabled (via a `w=1` GET parameter or clicking the button).

Comment: Thanks @Chris! It seems to be white space changes.. I checked the `hide whitespace changes`in the diff check, but the section that says "no changes" now says, "Whitespace-only changes"
Is there a way to take them off of the PR? I feel like they distract us from focusing on the actual code changes

Comment: If you want to remove them from the PR (which means merging the PR won't introduce these changes) you'll have to remove them from the source branch.